# Only some of the PDF thumbnails showing up?

Tags: 18.04, nautilus, thumbnails

Half of my PDFs have thumbnails and the rest have a generic "PDF" icon.

I tried deleting ~/.cache/thumbnails/fail but this doesn't seem to help.

The thumbnails that do get generated are created very slowly (much slower than it would take me to open the PDF)

Is there any way to try to troubleshoot this, for example, look at the logs somewhere?

Comment: I don't have a solution to this, but I've been experiencing the same problem. I installed Ubuntu 18.04 on 6-Oct-2018 and I *believe* this was not a problem then. Reason is, I recently cleared out old files from ~/.cache/thumbnail and this caused it to regenerate thumbnails for lots of documents including PDFs on my Desktop next time I logged in. Some of those took ages to generate and are now generic PDF icons where before they were thumbnails. When I installed the OS, I would've restored ~/Desktop files but *not* anything in ~/.cache hence I believe something has broken post-install.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very simple solution for Lubuntu 18.04 LXDE distro.

Remove Evince as your PDF reader and install Atril for PDF reading.

Atril also installs a thumbnailer which works flawlessly.

There might be a sequence issue with Evince thumbnailer. So I suggest to just uninstall Evince PDF reader.